# rails reading lines of file before upload with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upload a file in rails (using paperclip), and I want to process some of the file data before letting paperclip send it off to s3 storage. In my controller, I just grab the file parameter (which does give me a file) and then I try to read the lines into an array

```
csv_file = params[:activity][:data]

array = IO.readlines(csv_file.path)
```

The problem is, I'm only getting the last line of the file. I tried using .rewind, but still get just the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike readlines and I always use regular expressions. Try this.
End of line - \n

Answer (score 0):

Handy block structure to ensure that the file handle is closed:

```
File.open(csv_file.path) do |f|
  a = f.readlines
  process a...
end
```

Reading a whole file into memory might not be a good idea depending on the size of the files.

Comment: Thanks, but the same problem still persists - a[0] gives me the last line of the file and a[1] returns nothing. I'm guessing its something to do with paperclip :/